# CoreData relationship properties/attributes not setting

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, relationships

The data model i have set up is a one to many.
Round <----->>Holes
I setup and stored the Round properties/Attribute values in a setup VC, and saved it to core data. This works just great. In a new VC I want to add to the existing created Core Data record made previously, but this time add only to the relationship property(roundToHole) I have declared in the data model. However, when i set the values, they just keep coming back with (\n), no values are actually stored. See code below for comments

```
 @IBAction func saveBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let newFrequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Round")

    newFrequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "course = %@", courseName)
    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "course", ascending: true)
    newFrequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]

    var fetchedArray:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(newFrequest, error: nil)

    var results = fetchedArray[0] as NSManagedObject

    //This setter doesn't seem to be doing anything, only returns a (\n) value
    results.setValue("3", forKeyPath: "roundToHole.holeNum")
    context.save(nil)
```

SO.... What Am I doing wrong that it is not setting the relationship properties?